# GitHub Actions with a Self Hosted Windows-Runner "File not found: 'bash'"

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to write a Composite Run Step Action that runs on all platforms, including Windows.

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: flutter pub get
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-dir }}
```

When I omit shell, I get the error "Required parameter shell missing". This is odd, since I just want to use the default of the OS.

When I specify 'bash' I get an error `file not found 'bash'` on my Windows runners, though according to the docs "*When specifying a bash shell on Windows, the bash shell included with Git for Windows is used.*" https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell

I just want to run `flutter pub get` on all platforms from an action, using the default shell. Is there some simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the folder containing the `bash` executable is in the `PATH` environment variable of the Windows user that is running the GitHub Actions runner. The documentation you're referencing is about runners hosted by GitHub.

You get an error because `shell` is required for composite run actions. The reason is that, besides very simple scripts, you won't be able to run a script in different shells because of their big differences.

See also [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsshell)

Comment: Thanks for the info, so does this mean it's technically not possible to write a simple shell script that just works everywhere?

My only options are: 
* Customize the runner (we're using a bunch of self-hosted runners)
* Create a action for each shell I want to use, and copy and paste the commands between them

Seems odd that there is no way to just say: run this command, in the default shell.

Comment: You could write a shell script that could run everywhere. But this shell script would be constrained to only running executables with command line arguments. No conditionals, variables etc. There is not much overlap between Powershell (default on Windows) and Bash (default on Linux and macOs). Your best bet is to make sure `bash` (or your favorite shell) is available on all your runners and specifiy the shell in the compound action steps and the jobs of your workflows.

Comment: This is actually what I want in this case tho, as we're using a shared binary that is agnostic, for example my commands are:
`flutter pub get` 
`flutter build ${{ platform }}`. Do you know how I would do that? If I omit shell: it complains, it doesn't seem like there is any default or wildcard I can pass.

Comment: The basic idea is that we have 5 or 6 generic commands that only differ in one string, so we want to create a single action and just pass in the platform arg. Rather than duplicate the same code 6 times, or have to write 2 actions. We can customize the runners, just would be nice to not have that extra config step.

Comment: It's not possible. As the documentation states, `shell` is a required field for composite run actions.

Comment: Sad, but thanks for all the clarifications